# difference between two times along with am and pm in c#

Tags: c#, .net, time

I want to calculate time difference between start time and end time. For that am using the following code.

```
 string startTime = "3:10 PM";
 string endTime = "4:50 AM";
 TimeSpan duration =     DateTime.Parse(endTime).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(startTime));
```

this is giving correct answers in most of the cases but in case of above values it is giving me answer as "10h20m". but the difference between 4:50 AM and 3:10Pm is 13h40m.

How I can calculate exact difference?

Comment: "*but the difference between 4:50 AM and 3:10Pm is 13h40m*". Are you sure? Remeber, the difference between 4:50 AM and 4:50 PM is 12 hours.

Comment: No, the difference betwen 4:50am and 3:10pm is 10 hours and 20 minutes in the most obvious way of calculating it... 10 hours after 4:50am is 2:50pm, and 20 minutes later than that is 3:10pm. Now sure, you could *also* add 13 hours and 40 minutes to 3:10pm to get to 4:50am, but what makes that the "better" answer in your view? It sounds like the fact that you've got a *start* that needs to be the start is the relevant information, but there's nothing in that code that will say anything about that.

Comment: You need to include the date also.

Comment: Also note that the TimeSpan given by the code you've given will be *negative* - it won't actually be 10 hours and 20 minutes. We need to see the rest of your code for what you're doing with the TimeSpan.

Comment: my question will be like A started working at 3:10 Pm and completed his work at 4:50 am. how much time A took to finish his work?
My calculation will go like 3:10 pm to 3:10 am it will be 12 hours and from 3:10 to 4:50 it will be 1 h 40 min together will become 13h40m.

Comment: No, it doesn't give `10h20m` - it gives `-10h20m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
 string startTime = "3:10 PM";
 string endTime = "4:50 AM";

 DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(startTime);
 DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(endTime);
 if (start > end)
    end = end.AddDays(1);

 TimeSpan duration = end.Subtract(start);

 Console.WriteLine(duration.ToString());
```

Comment: This is also a nice approach, and maybe more accurate than mine, as it deals with the problem with OP code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that what you want to calculate involves different day. As a workaround, you could do something like this:

```
string startTime = "3:10 PM";
string endTime = "4:50 AM";
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Parse(endTime) - DateTime.Parse(startTime);
if (duration < TimeSpan.Zero)
{
    duration += TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}
```

Comment: I think you're taking the right approach, but it can be expressed a lot more simply. Mind if I edit?

Comment: Go ahead @JonSkeet

Comment: I agree that's better. Thank you @JonSkeet